# grep: (standard input): Bad file descriptor

Tags: c, linux, unix, fork, pipe

I am trying to change the stdin to a pipe outlet and stdout to another file and using grep.  I get the following error:

```
grep: (standard input): Bad file descriptor
```

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

int main()
{
        pid_t childpid;
        int fds[2];
        int stat;
        int fd = open("temp", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
        int old_in = dup(STDIN_FILENO);
        int old_out = dup(STDOUT_FILENO);
        if ((childpid = fork()) != 0)
        {
                wait(&stat);
                close(fds[1]);
                dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
                dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
                system("grep hello");
                dup2(old_in, STDIN_FILENO);
                dup2(old_out, STDOUT_FILENO);
                close(fds[0]);
                close(fd);
        }

        else if (childpid == 0)
        {
                close(fds[0]);
                write(fds[1], "hello how are you", 100);
                close(fds[1]);
                return 0;

        }

        else
        {
                fprintf(stderr, "ERROR:\n");
                exit(1);
        }
        return 0;
}
```

So basically I am writing a string to the write outlet of a pipe and using the other outlet of the pipe (the read) as stdin for grep, and outputting stdout to another file.  I've removed the return from the childpid and also tried using another file as the stdin instead, but still get the same error.

Comment: Use `execvp` instead of `system` inside your child branch after `fork`. Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: You don't seem to ever set the values of `fds` (for example, by calling `pipe(fds)`.) Also, you really should check return codes of system calls, even if you don't think they will fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple problems!  Amongst others:

- You don't call `pipe(fds);` so you don't have a pipe.
- Childish code (`write(fds[1], "hello how are you", 100);`)

  - You should include a newline at the end of the line.
  - You should only write as many characters as there are in the string, and there aren't 100 characters in the string shown.
- Parental code (the block after `if ((childpid = fork()) != 0)`)

  - You don't need to reinstate the file descriptors after the `system` because you're about to exit.
  - You could use one of the `exec*()` functions instead of `system()`.
  - In general, you should not wait for the child to exit; there can be too much data pushed into the pipe for the child to be able to finish before the parent reads anything.  In this case, it should be OK, but beware.
  - You should not really execute `grep` with the extra file descriptors open (`old_in` and `old_out`), but they go away when you don't reinstate things after the `system()` call.
  - You should close `fds[0]` after you've duplicated it (and before you run `grep`).

#### Working code

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    pid_t childpid;
    int fds[2];
    int fd = open("temp", O_WRONLY | O_APPEND);
    if (pipe(fds) != 0)
        return 1;
    if ((childpid = fork()) != 0)
    {
        close(fds[1]);
        dup2(fds[0], STDIN_FILENO);
        dup2(fd, STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(fds[0]);
        close(fd);
        execlp("grep", "grep", "hello", (char *)0);
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to execute grep\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else if (childpid == 0)
    {
        const char data[] = "hello how are you\nvery well thanks\n";
        close(fds[0]);
        write(fds[1], data, sizeof(data)-1);
        close(fds[1]);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR:\n");
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent, I didn't realize how ugly my code was (need some sleep maybe :) ).